# Wie kann man die Wortbildung mit '-t/digen' verstehen?

Tags: meaning, etymology

['-igen' ist ein Suffix in Deutsch](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/-ig#Suffix,_bei_Verben), da sind viele Wörter mit '-igen' gebildet. Außerdem gibt es auch Wörter, deren '-t/digen' nichts mit '-igen' zu tun haben.

Zum Beispiel,

> bewältigen bestätigen verständigen entschuldigen erledigen erkundigen kündigen

Es scheint, '-t/digen' gilt auch nicht als ein Suffix. Dann bekomme ich die Frage, was die Regel der Wortbildung mit '-t/digen' ist und wie mann es verstehen kann.

Comment: Inwiefern ist *-igen* ein eigenes Suffix? Der Link geht auf *-ig*, *-en* wäre dann lediglich eine Deklinationsendung.

Comment: @amadeusamadeus Ich habe es im Abschnitt [Suffix, bei Verben](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/-ig#Suffix,_bei_Verben) gesehen. Darüber habe ich nicht genug Erfahrung. Könntest du es weiter entdecken und mir erklären?

Comment: Zunächst einmal muss ich mich korrigieren: ich las zuerst nur den Abschnitt *Suffix, bei Adjektiven*, deshalb schrieb ich *Deklinations*endung. Bei Verben ist es natürlich eine *Konjugations*endung. Genau darum geht es: *-ig* ist das Wortbildungssuffix, das aus einem Substantiv oder Adjektiv ein Verb macht, *-en* ist hingegen ein Flexionssuffix. Als Beispiel: *fest* wird zu *fest-ig-en*, aber *-en* gehört nicht zu *-ig-*, vgl. *ihr fest-ig-t*, wo *-t* anstelle der Infinitivendung *-en* tritt. Daher ist *-igen* kein eigenes Suffix, sondern die Kombination *-ig-* (Wortbildung) + *-en* (Flexion).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Die Verben, die auf *-igen* enden, gehen in der einen oder anderen Form auf ein Adjetiv mit dem Suffiy *-ig* zurück. Verb und Adjektiv können sich dabei aber schon weit von einander entfernt haben: Die Bedeutung des Verbs kann sich zum Teil stark von der des Adjektivs entfernt haben; es kann sogar sein, dass das Adjektiv gar nicht mehr in dieser Form im Gegenwartsdeutsch existiert.

Das gilt auch für deine Beispiele:

- *bestätigen* ← *stetig*
- *verständigen* ← *verständig*
- *entschuldigen* ← *schuldig*
- *erledigen* ← *ledig*
- *erkundigen* ← *kundig*
- *kündigen* ← *kundig*

Auf den ersten Blick fällt das Verben *bewältigen* aus diesem Schema. Es gibt gegenwärtig kein Adjektiv **wältig* oder **bewältig*. Wohl gibt es aber die Worte *Gewalt*, *gewaltig*, sowie *verwalten* und das Verb *walten*. Tatsächlich hieß es im Mittelhochdeutschen noch *gewältigen*<sup>[1]</sup> (ein Verb, das es heute nicht mehr gibt), aus dem sich dann wohl *bewältigen* (und auch *überwältigen*) gebildet haben.

---

[1]: [Pfeiffer: Etymologisches Wörterbuch des Deutschen](https://www.dwds.de/wb/bew%C3%A4ltigen)

Comment: Fehlerquelle: *g* wird im Nord-Deutschen typisch lenisiert zu /y/ o.ä., ähnlich wie *l* in einigen Situationen nur approximiert wird (vgl. bspw. *beeilen*, eindeutiger in Niederländisch *gouden* "golden", weiter westlich in Französisch gänzlich regular *battailon*). Zudem existieren ein Suffixe wie Urindogermanisch (PIE) \*-dhlom, \*-tlom, deren Abkunft im Germanischen nicht geklärt ist.

Comment: @vectory Ich verstehe nicht richtig, worauf sich dein Kommentar bezieht. Kannst du das genauer erklären? Danke :)

Comment: Weiß ich auch nicht. Das Beispiel \*-dhlom ist an den Haaren herbeigezogen, aber der Anspruch ist schon ernstgemeint, *g* /y/ zu beachten (also *-(d)ien*, . Vergleich etwa [Proto-Germanic/-janą](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Reconstruction:Proto-Germanic/-jan%C4%85), OHG *-en, - ien* (wenngleich dort angedeutet wird es sei überall geschwunden, ich trau dem Friedel nicht).